# PowerShell Cert expiration Script

Tags: html, powershell, smtp

I am writing a script to detect SSO ADFS expiring certificates. I am sending the list in an email. I am trying to sort the list by most expired to least expired in an email.

I want to sort this list by days, not alphabetically

[image: 1]

```
Clear
$Body=""
$Body = "<b>SSO Certificate Expiration:</b><br/>"


$ExpirationThreshold = 30
$CurrentDate = Get-Date
$ComparisonDate = (Get-Date).AddDays($ExpirationThreshold)
$FixFormat = Get-Date $ComparisonDate

$Trusts = Get-AdfsClaimsProviderTrust |
Select name, @{Name='TokenSigningCertificates'; Expression={[string]::join(";", ($_.TokenSigningCertificates.NotAfter| 
Group-Object Name | 
Foreach-Object {$_.Group | Sort-Object * | Select-Object -Last 1}))}} |
Sort-Object -Property name


foreach ($Trust in $Trusts) {
    $Dates = [nullable[datetime]]$Trust.TokenSigningCertificates 
 if ($Dates -ne $null -and $Dates.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") -ge $CurrentDate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") -and $Dates.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") -lt $FixFormat.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")) {

    $Body = $Body + (($Trust.Name + " cert expiring in: " + '<b style="background-color:yellow">' + ($Dates - $CurrentDate).ToString("dd") + '</b>' +" days<br/>"))
 }
 elseif ($Dates -ne $null -and $Dates.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") -lt $CurrentDate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")) {

    $Body = $Body + (($Trust.Name + " already expired (" + '<b style="color:red">' + ($CurrentDate - $Dates).ToString("dd") + '</b>' + " days ago)<br/>"))
 }
 }
 
 $Body = $Body + "<br/><br/><i>This Script Was Run From: $env:COMPUTERNAME</i>"
 
Write-host "Sending Email"
Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer "*****" -Body $Body -Credential $PSCredSG -From "*****" -To "*****" -Subject "Expiring SSO Certs" -BodyAsHtml
```

Answer (score 0):

Using FRegex :

```
$filename = "c:\temp\test.txt"
$pattern = '^.*\((?<days>\d+).*'

$certificates = Select-String -Path $filename -Pattern $pattern
$table = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
foreach($certificate in $certificates.Matches)
{
   $newRow = New-Object -TypeName psobject
   $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Days -NotePropertyValue ([int]$certificate.Groups["days"].Value)
   $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Certificate -NotePropertyValue $certificate.Value
   $table.Add($newRow)  | Out-Null
}
$table = $table | Sort-Object -Property Days -Descending
$table
```

Used following input file

```
ABC already expirer (304 days ago)
CDE already expirer (200 days ago)
FGH already expirer (180 days ago)
IJK already expirer (40 days ago)
LMN already expirer (80 days ago)
```

Results :

```
Days Certificate
---- -----------
 304 ABC already expirer (304 days ago)
 200 CDE already expirer (200 days ago)
 180 FGH already expirer (180 days ago)
  80 LMN already expirer (80 days ago)
  40 IJK already expirer (40 days ago)
```